# C++ Event System - Polymorphic Events and Event Handlers

Tags: c++

I've written the most basic Event System I can think of. I come from a javascript background so I followed the `On`, `Off`, `Emit` syntax. The intention is to be able to create an `EventSystem` that can `Emit` any type of derived `Event` object and have the appropriate handlers called.

**Please note, I am stuck in C++98 for reasons**

So far my best idea is to have a simple `Event` object and a typedef for each `Event` type to handle it.

```
class Event {};
class AlarmEvent : Event {};
class ErrorEvent : Event {};

typedef void (*EventHandler)(Event event);
typedef void (*AlarmEventHandler)(AlarmEvent event);
typedef void (*ErrorEventHandler)(ErrorEvent event);
```

My issue is I want my modules to be able to attach as easy as possible.

```
int main()
{
    Module module;

    EventSystem es;
    Event shutdown_event("shutdown");    
    AlarmEvent alarm_event("alarm", "Oh crap");

    es.On("shutdown", module.OnEvent);
    es.On("shutdown", module.OnEvent);
    es.On("alarm", module.OnAlarmEvent);

    es.Emit(shutdown_event);
    es.Emit(alarm_event);
}
```

But looking at the `EventSystem`

```
class EventSystem {
    public: 
        void On(std::string id, EventHandler handler);
        void Emit(Event event);
        void GetEventHandlers(std::string id, std::vector<EventHandler> *&handlers);
        std::map<std::string, std::vector<EventHandler> > events;
};
```

I'd need an `On`, `GetEventHandlers`, and `events` property for every event type. This would quickly become terrible. Is there a better path where I can use a template to allow `EventSystem` to stay as simple as possible?

Comment: I don't understand *"I'd need an On, GetEventHandlers, and events property for every event type."*. Are you talking about event types not inheriting from`Event`? Because you are working on `Event` in `EventSystem` and your other events are inheriting from `Event`. So I don't see why you would need to write these methods for every new event inheriting from `Event`.

Comment: `EventHandler` is a type, so unless I can extend functions, I cannot pass an `AlarmEventHandler` to the `On` function.

Answer (score 1):

C++98 is old, older than variadic templates. The following emulates variadic templates with linked lists, which is very much suboptimal, but it should work.

```
// linked lists for "variadic" templates
struct Nil { };
template<typename X, typename XS>
struct Cons { };

// utility type
struct BlackHole {
    template<typename T>
    BlackHole(const T&) { }
};
// anything can be converted to a BlackHole implicitly, but it's a "worse"
// conversion than being converted to a base class

// I would template your event system over every event type
// this implementation only works properly if more derived events appear before their bases
template<typename Events> // e.g. Events = Cons<AlarmEvent, Cons<ErrorEvent, Cons<Event, Nil>>>
class EventSystem;

template<>
class EventSystem<Nil> {
    protected:
    // see below for Emit/EmitEmitted thing
    // usage of BlackHole means that e.g. if calling with AlarmEvent
    // and only overloads for Event and BlackHole are visible
    // then the former will be chosen, since the latter conversion is worse
    // can't just say template<typename T> EmitEmitted(T const&) { }
    void EmitEmitted(BlackHole) { }

    public:
    // these overloads exist so the using declarations ahead don't fail
    // for maximum type-safety, create a private type and
    // make it an argument of each, so they can never be called
    // using Emit/EmitEmitted creates type safety; again, see below
    void Emit() { }
    // On has easy type safety: you just can't call it for an unknown type
    void On() { }
    // GetEventHandlers doesn't really make sense anyway
    // I don't think you need it, you can't have a vector of mixed handlers
    // so why bother?
};
template<typename X, typename XS>
class EventSystem<Cons<X, XS> > : public EventSystem<XS> {
    std::vector<void (*)(X)> handlers;

    protected:
    // "forward" all the EmitEmitted overloads made for XS
    using EventSystem<XS>::EmitEmitted;
    // overload for the specific case of an X
    void EmitEmitted(X x) {
        // fire all of the X-specific handlers
        for(typename std::vector<void (*)(X)>::iterator i = handlers.begin(); i != handlers.end(); ++i) {
            (*i)(x);
        }
        // call the rest of the handlers
        EventSystem<XS>::EmitEmitted(x);
    }

    public:
    // more "forwarding"
    using EventSystem<XS>::Emit;
    void Emit(X x) {
        return EmitEmitted(x);
    }
    // suppose you have an EventSystem<Cons<std::string, Nil> >
    // if you Emit an int, say, then you want this to fail
    // thus the overload of Emit in EventSystem<Nil> should not be
    // a catch-all or anything
    // however, if you emit a std::string, then you need to recursively
    // emit from EventSystem<Nil>, to handle any handlers for superclasses
    // now you don't want it to explode
    // solution? two functions
    // Emit is the public entry point, and fails on unknown types
    // EmitEmitted is named so because, once it's called, the type
    // is known to be known, and will/has been emitted by at least one layer
    // it no-ops once the base case is reached
    // it is protected, and it is where the actual logic is

    // easy now, right?
    using EventSystem<XS>::On;
    void On(void (*handler)(X)) {
        handlers.push_back(handler);
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
struct Event {
    std::string message;
    Event(std::string message) : message(message) { }
};
void HandleEvent(Event e) {
    std::cerr << e.message << "\n";
}
class AlarmEvent : public Event {
    int hour;
    int minute;
    static std::string BuildMessage(int hour, int minute) {
        std::stringstream builder;
        builder << "Alarm: " << std::setfill('0');
        builder << std::setw(2) << hour << ":";
        builder << std::setw(2) << minute;
        return builder.str();
    }
    friend void HandleAlarm(AlarmEvent);

    public:
    AlarmEvent(int hour, int minute) : Event(BuildMessage(hour, minute)), hour(hour), minute(minute) { }
};
void HandleAlarm(AlarmEvent a) {
    // please ignore the fact that this is very stupid
    if((a.hour + (a.minute / 60)) % 24 < 12) std::cerr << "AM Alarm\n";
    else std::cerr << "PM Alarm\n";
}
struct ErrorEvent : Event {
    ErrorEvent(std::string message) : Event(message) { }
};
void HandleError(ErrorEvent) {
    static int count = 1;
    std::cerr << "Error " << count++ << "\n";
}

int main() {
    EventSystem<Cons<AlarmEvent, Cons<ErrorEvent, Cons<Event, Nil> > > > system;
    // all handled by overload resolution
    // no need to say what type you're dealing with
    system.On(HandleEvent);
    system.On(HandleAlarm);
    system.On(HandleError);
    // doesn't work
    // system.On(std::exit)

    system.Emit(ErrorEvent("Bad things"));
    system.Emit(AlarmEvent(2, 30));
    system.Emit(Event("Something happened"));
    system.Emit(ErrorEvent("More bad things"));
    system.Emit(AlarmEvent(11, 67));
    // doesn't work
    // system.Emit(5);
}
```

Not sure that all the example code is C++98, but that doesn't matter. [It appears to work nicely](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAA5SW9ABk8tTADljAI0zEu3XgAdUCwuto9QxNzUh8/NTpbeycjV3ceXiUVSNoGAmZiAiDjUwtkzFUA9MyCaMcXNw8kjKyckPzasrsKuKrEgEpFVANiZA4AcikAZjtkQywAanFhnQA3QqJiGexxAAYAQXWNgHodydY7AGtMdAO8BQIFSZpiaclJOcy8ZnwJB8mCTCMvYS%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%2BqBfKopwgNZSpckohKuKwqAljcJC0UYhA7Ng/kEEFhCdpeojOYqXIGAozDAISqD/mKcamomBIiNc3pqvuVE0X%2B/psIcoiToQCCTOxmRcSeUVkfsIhnHQz67m4nmvNctxGXe0baLG8YytGxCEnMFx4M47C1VySGBkhPmcW4pWsJCwbIAgvhaKSfi0P0DaEn8Xx3DWbh1oGV5lsQFaGi51YiPmIp8LFIpxUeWFohq5L4XqlmhSFwWdhAuptpcUh2g6bJXYqcyoHgZw/T9/0pf17D2nK4OaQqSpeAY42pk5EN1bt/YtT%2BqDtfuAAeFxPVGs2xa2WCKcQaoBIWCCYK8kzoHQd03MwEKTfsnVGMwlNGMYAqYAAtHFVCYNipLIENOk9h%2BYHK2ePXoALAHMCcuY9YNwDGN1SX7nGCCbTTbNHgGkz2HuK1Fac2t0yVP2BcF8MRor7P/BL67MLL2KItGwB87Qm2YO5yhebVUMw35hAQCjrKuvjXIAPKBo21zsxu/sy3LWIgAuPSTA9lyFbQPMsEt%2BudU2Bi0EctBeTN5Jx9DZxZ8nYNpxj0X7AA4nLImSg17AXZzqDodXAwikrS1HsLetKEyhKeiWzBYtrE5c3Pp4%2Bs3pcGHbUdnIQpKLqfAY842Cw9gsqi%2Bab/nkxGjbaJPGFGq5UYlggI8zg7Js2WMMAAYhyKECJhjylejpd6WodTElJHhZBRJqRyU2AZZSxk1LfAxHxWYJIqSWUsiXLGONkBdXoCZdSxDMGkTlLVS46AQAgCfksDE8czgQAAFQdAgESDollP7oG/hpWqtl7KdjxgPAmxZbhb2IFrD4RVdqJ1%2BmFCMxM2roGuMLKYnUMG1Vdn6FS%2BCzIMJWOwuGf1nawO1ro0mZxOqzQULiNMVBUyFSJv%2BJsRJO4Jzsdo9AQjJjkxTvKI0v9BZ4CGtGOuptZpEmlp4v8PixESPxkaW4EA0GUlYewzhJBuFd0mPwwRwibEgEIG4NUvk8DTEYpMLJx0KKuGAHYZOIcmlgDADMJibSLoUSsD02B9xZAyDwFE2qMSlT8JmRASJGl5mKn7msgmtdISzSGpXZJbNWkT2OnMpUFjTIYhMSRWxnt7FhJWY4/G/cpHY0OMgORsSAJAXuJIJRmR8CRQeKYra5i8EXOsdckAP1VlKh4Zo8JkSrI5KVENAgvRAwhIIP9B50SlQbOuuuAwMF1onyOQ/Js5z6E6CIToIpIAgS%2BikvzEizTVjp32AVa%2BmiDZ2FEgHTMu1Axcq3mub0V5uxUD5jJdlDZYoaOcRzU2P0kwYrBVSiyLKFBrWnGcVuIpXDaxjCwAgq1JbqN8p6MVkUZVrRLAeMgSZ/xcu%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%2BhOKCV7Ql2S/lzAEBiupaiSp6BGk4Xjy/jgE8EBYuYDE/FggbCUBuDuBiDEuVysJVM71ysABWHQtBKxqf7jgiqHFqrdQoa8nxsXmH415a0pcym1v%2BVoDyNLLD7w%2BOy62aQBgIToAALJ5dSxANb2qHVbbsLt1rmyjuiBc/iIMp2ZwgbU5s7MZ2Fo9dmD8yqnES7FkG8D91ctvFLQgPmNY%2BYRG/bWf9773W9JQ/a%2BwpQBASwQEkCjTHOh1u9EhyT4sTkgUo/mWjkC5P1zY/pXLfHhOGfbd28po0qL0WfYB8QCiQJxnpbRrk0CVhJi1eOaDowEAZciWR/KF5VCPlKnl4127S5SQPZ218QrsaIAnbO5dlLCVFNa4Ao9vXXRSfEHN70G3HOvhlaty1vu1WXTVbU1L%2BrMu5ezdi8wZ7BLfh50JHgYArcEmzUlaCbKh8rxXjDEeS4RKYa1T/FAZgFE7uTIqdnp3hJ9g2jWKJ%2B4w3JiSG4KZyYnA2d0v6IJBnxYNjnZm1VcQo3xvU5F8ofsDeuvN4eAABTbzLzvY2JtK49xsKLoIBJCViyXZbMJaoL5IJl17fp%2Btu%2BX41nflXnle/lD78ROBBIkCaxf4SJ5g%2BKkuMzCja40BNxFIM2vymB9N6BxTh46/usfA/4hiv5yByBD6SAT7d4QGTYz7bBbbhy9wrbyLsZWLUpdqzDq53hiRMj8TX6STMToE6D4EapMIspkKarxo04EzqJtJnDOBHgKpnB7L6A8gBAFpRh%2BpdhRjPSTiNinjkgnz5gJJYBsCtglhlQsKWIUQ9x1Zn4K6f5SEyHS6zaK6SGmTSG0AQCyHsD/6qEypcyzylqvjawbjqE9x0pVqEAiIjjxZSE/RX6L6NbFjSAcxWrAAAgPCiYKHqH2GYH0AE6kjDCl56G2E%2BHBRNZOEPAMCoAEhuFHIwRaDOyeEhFGimEogUT2H/6ZbFjnbfKoRdhHzuHFheFUFpHfAZHhF%2BEEAQCcCcCkg2hQglEi5cgGEKAHwvjEBHAmF2HhHDYhFOgDBdCsAgADDDYDCkCmADBrDjGoAjE6CgEyDrhLg7QjCcDjEEAjHTGiakBHAgDDbcAURmBmA2i1HDCcDDaSBrAACc3Aaww2w2QgIx3A4xRgXAawawExmxMxIx4xCgIAHxGxUxgxpAcAsASAVahQPIJA5AlAmQ7hw%2BIgygDAtqkxaxpAaAPwEIzMdACJ9grAyJbcXx6JMRXgEIVQwAVxkgxJmJk8GcPIBJN6RJEJyAGwxA7hPxlg78yA6QAKHJNAtCtcHAPA/AggwgogKACx8g%2BmfxkAXQX4qQfxAw0s7Wgy7wUy0gVxZgkwksuI6AIgagyAvxyxQpig7WdguJSJKJIxaxQxIxYxnxQJpAsxAw5MxxksNo1ewAyA1CVxFEkgtEXJUJdwTW%2BASw9wZx9o8xMgcg6xXx2xbMrwVQycOxIA3Aw2FEpxRxNoZg3AUIVxdxNxDxwxAwzxDp0xTpHJfxAJcZtpAwkg4xkx5ZzpsZQJ2xtYAQqZQAA). Also, there's a lot of copying going on here. It may be advisable to change handlers from `void (*)(T)` (which necessitates a copy) to `void (*)(T&)` or `void (*)(T const&)`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll need some time to look through this

Answer (score 0):

If your functions took references or pointers, then you would be able to pass polymorphic child types into them. So then you only need one type of function ptr.

```
typedef void (*EventHandler)(Event& event);
```

or

```
typedef void (*EventHandler)(Event* event);
```

Comment: I tried that - I changed my `On` function definition to take an `EventHandler`, but it complains when I pass it an `AlarmEventHandler`, `error: invalid conversion from 'void (*)(AlarmEvent&)' to 'void (*)(Event&)' [-fpermissive]`

Comment: Are you implying that handlers should use `typeid` or something to check if the incoming event is of the correct type?